# AWS Cognito Error: No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

```
var normalAuth = async (username, password) => {   
    try{
        var user = await Auth.signIn(username, password)
        console.log(user)
        if(user.challengeName === "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED"){
            console.log("assigning new password!")
            user = await Auth.completeNewPassword(user, "password") // give the user a new password. this would NOT be included in any kind of production code, its only here as a work around
            console.log(user)
        } // work around. users created in the console are only given temporary passwords, and as such have no authorization
        // setting a new password will fix this

        console.log(await Auth.currentCredentials()) // THIS THROWS AN ERROR?!?!
        setAuthState(false) // auth is no longer in progress
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to grab the tokens from my Amplify user after authenticating but I'm receiving the error

```
No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access
```

This is pretty strange because I'm not using an identity pool at all. My baseline assumption was that I shouldn't need to provide an identity pool ID at all in my amplify config.

config looks like this

```
var amplifyConfig = {
    Auth: {
        mandatorySignIn: false,
        region: "us-east-1",
        userPoolId: "mypoolid",
        userPoolWebClientId: "myclientid"
    }
}
```

The really weird part is that the tokens are actually there in `user` after I authenticate. It's only when I try and retrieve them this way specifically that an error is thrown.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: `currentCredentials` fetches AWS credentials. you're looking for `currentSession` which returns the session data containing the tokens.

Comment: Why do you need the tokens?